# WebGL 2D Texture Display Error

Tags: safari, webgl

I'm having an odd problem. On Chrome and Firefox, everything is fine, but in Safari when I load 2D images onto a particular panel (using WebGL) I get the following error:

WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: packImage error

The images are greyscale 128x128 jpegs. I can provide more code if necessary, but I'm having trouble even finding out what this packImage error means.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bug in Safari :-(  It doesn't correctly handle grayscale images in WebGL.

Comment: Haha, thanks again gman! Is the solution to re-encode the images or make the texture display as a 3 or 4 channel image?

Comment: Use a different image format or ignore Safari since they still have not really shipped WebGL to normal users.

Comment: @gman, do you have a link to a bug report or another source?

Comment: [I checked in a test](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/textures/gl-teximage.html). Safari doesn't pass. I didn't file a bug though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that after loading the texture, you just need to set the appropriate format. For instance:

```
var tex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/grayscale.png');
tex.format = THREE.LuminanceFormat;
```